# WinAPI - Character encoding on standard output to the text file

Tags: c, winapi, encoding, stdout

I have code which change code page of console for UTF-8, but when i want to redirect output to .txt file, it's not working. Maybe because file is in ANSI format? How can I solve this problem in the best way?

```
#include <windows.h> 
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{ 
    if(!SetConsoleCP(65001))
    {
        printf("\nSetConsoleCP failed with %d\n", GetLastError()); 
    }

    if(!SetConsoleOutputCP(65001))
    {
        printf("\nSetConsoleOutputCP failed with %d\n", GetLastError());
    }

    system("chcp && ping google.com > log.txt");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "it's not working"... how?

Comment: Default my code page of console is 852, but I want output to file in Unicode. 
For example:
> chcp 65001 && ping google.com > log.txt       <---- it's not working
> chcp 65001 && dir > log.txt       <---- it's working

Comment: Have you considered NOT using `system()` in this manner at all? Microsoft has APIs for sending pings - [`IcmpSendEcho()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366050.aspx), [`IcmpSendEcho2()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366051.aspx), and [`IcmpSendEcho2Ex()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb309069.aspx). Send a ping programmably and then write the results yourself to the output file any way you want. Don't involve the command interpreter at all.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to start the console with "cmd /w", and use utf16 console writing commands.

System() is part of your C compilers library, and it depends on what the library does internally. (e.g. does it start with cmd /w or just cmd?), does "ping" write to the console using "w" variants?

Comment: When I change command on system("chcp && dir > log.txt"); , then it's everything ok. So, this is problem with ping program, right?

Comment: It is a problem with cmd.exe not being wired for unicode. cmd /w should put it in unicode mode, but applications must then also use the unicode apis. Afaik the 65001 hacks are often quoted but pretty defunct in practice.